# Getting null reference from a shopping system

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, reference, null

For Context, I'm pretty new to Unity, so I've followed a tutorial. Here is the link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oie-G5xuQNA

And for easier access to the code I will also be posting it here:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ButtonInfo : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int ItemID;
    public Text PriceText;
    public Text QuantityText;
    public GameObject ShopManager;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        PriceText.text = "Price: $" + ShopManager.GetComponent<ShopManagerScript>().shopItems[2, ItemID].ToString();
        QuantityText.text = ShopManager.GetComponent<ShopManagerScript>().shopItems[3, ItemID].ToString();

    }
}
```

And also here is the second script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ShopManagerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int [,] shopItems = new int[5,5];
    public float coins;
    public Text CoinsText;


    void Start()
    {
        CoinsText.text = "Coins" + coins.ToString();

        // ID's
        shopItems[1, 1] = 1;
        shopItems[1, 2] = 2;
        shopItems[1, 3] = 3;
        shopItems[1, 4] = 4;

        // Price
        shopItems[2, 1] = 10;
        shopItems[2, 2] = 20;
        shopItems[2, 3] = 30;
        shopItems[2, 4] = 40;

        // Quantity
        shopItems[3, 1] = 1;
        shopItems[3, 2] = 1;
        shopItems[3, 3] = 1;
        shopItems[3, 4] = 1;


    }

    public void Buy()
    {
        GameObject ButtonRef = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Event").AddComponent<EventSystem>().currentSelectedGameObject;

        if(coins >= shopItems[2, ButtonRef.GetComponent<ButtonInfo>().ItemID])
        {
            coins -= shopItems[2, ButtonRef.GetComponent<ButtonInfo>().ItemID];
            shopItems[3, ButtonRef.GetComponent<ButtonInfo>().ItemID]++;
            CoinsText.text = "Coins" + coins.ToString();
            ButtonRef.GetComponent<ButtonInfo>().QuantityText.text = shopItems[3, ButtonRef.GetComponent<ButtonInfo>().ItemID].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

And the last thing: Here is the error message itself:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
> ShopManagerScript.Buy () (at Assets/Scrips/UI/Shop System/ShopManagerScript.cs:43)

Comment: Which line is 43 in `ShopManagerScript`? Is it `if(coins >= shopItems[2, ButtonRef.GetComponent<ButtonInfo>().ItemID])`? If so, there's probably no `ButtonInfo` attached to `ButtonRef`, and so the `GetComponent<ButtonInfo>()` call is returning null, and the exception is caused by the `.ItemID` operation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like in your Buy() method you are calling *AddComponent* to add an EventSystem to your object tagged as "Event". Most likely this object already has an EventSystem so it cannot add another and that is providing a null reference to your ButtonRef object.
You most likely want to be calling GetComponent there instead to get the already existing EventSystem component